# ImageButton is not being enabled when using AsyncPostBackTrigger in ajax update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-ajax

i am using asp.net with c#. i have two image buttons : open and delete.
By default they are disabled i.e. `imgOpen.Enabled = false; imgDelete.Enabled = false;`.
I have a GridView which shows search results from table. GridView contains a radio button which when selected, should enable Open and delete image button.
if I won't use ajax update panel, then every time i select a radio button my page reloads and it's quite disturbing and not friendly.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateRadioButton" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoBtnFileOption" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rdoBtnFileOption_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" />
               </ContentTemplate>
               <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoBtnFileOption" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
               </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>



protected void rdoBtnFileOption_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgOpen.Enabled = true;
        imgDelete.Enabled = true;

        RadioButton curretnRdo = sender as RadioButton;
        GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)curretnRdo.NamingContainer;
        int index = currentRow.RowIndex;
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow grv in grdSearchResults.Rows)
            {
                if (grv.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && grv.RowIndex != index)
                {
                    RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton();
                    rdo = (RadioButton)(grv.FindControl("rdoBtnFileOption"));
                    rdo.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            form.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", form.MessageBoxButtons.OK, form.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

These two line are not working for me.

```
imgOpen.Enabled = true;
imgDelete.Enabled = true;
```

Please Suggest any approach.
I hope i am quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using AsyncPostBack, the contents should be in Update panel also.

you can use another Asp:UpdatePanel with **UpdateMode="Always"** having your images in it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgOpen" runat="server" ImageUrl="" Visible="false" AlternateText="this is Open Image" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="" Visible="false" AlternateText="this is Delete Image" />
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

May this Help You.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

Wrap your `imgDelete` with another `UpdatePanel` and set `UpdateMode=Conditional` and set Trigger

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateRadioButton" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Image ID="imgOpen" runat="server"/>
   <asp:Image ID="imgDelete" runat="server"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoBtnFileOption" 
      EventName="CheckedChanged" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

or `set UpdateMode="Always" and No Triggers`

Comment: Two points i want to highlight with your solution: 1. My imagebuttons are in header section where i can't keep my radio button.even if i put these imagebuttons in update panel error is generated saying `ControlID="rdoBtnFileOption" `. 2. `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in update panel of radio button enables abnormal behavior of radio button such as multiple selection. which is not expected. Thanks.

Comment: @AjayVerma, yes please